# Unable to change default view of google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Working on building an interactive map and would like the map to load on road view as opposed to satellite (which is what it is right now).

I tried adding this: mapTypeId: 'roadmap', under the var options section, but doesn't seem to work. Anyone else run into similar issues?

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['map'],
    'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyC0cSTnym-r836gkhPRgER9MWycFRtDMrI'
  });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap () {
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('string', 'Address');
     data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
     data.addColumn('string', 'Marker')

      data.addRows([
        ['11 East 29th Street, New York, NY, United States', 'Home',   
        'blue' ],
        ['33 St, New York NY, 10016 United States', '6 train station',   
        'pink'],
        ['Union Square, New York, NY 10003',    'Union Square', 'pink' 
        ],
     ]);
     var url = 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-
    map-markers/48/';

  var options = {
    zoomLevel: 10,
    showTooltip: true,
    showInfoWindow: true,
    useMapTypeControl: true,
    icons: {
      blue: {
        normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Azure-icon.png',
        selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Azure-icon.png'
      },
      green: {
        normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Chartreuse-icon.png',
        selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Right-Chartreuse-
    icon.png'
      },
      pink: {
        normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Flag-3-Right-Pink-icon.png',
        selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Flag-2-Right-Pink-icon.png'
        }
      }
    };
    var map = new 
    google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

   map.draw(data, options);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#configuration-options):

> **mapType**
> The type of map to show. Possible values are 'normal', 'terrain', 'satellite', 'hybrid', or the ID of a custom map type, if any were created.
> Type: string
> Default: 'hybrid'

so this will display a "Road Map":

```
mapType: "normal",
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/t8rdgp59/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['map'],
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyC0cSTnym-r836gkhPRgER9MWycFRtDMrI'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

function drawMap() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Address');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Marker')

  data.addRows([
    ['11 East 29th Street, New York, NY, United States', 'Home',
      'blue'
    ],
    ['33 St, New York NY, 10016 United States', '6 train station',
      'pink'
    ],
    ['Union Square, New York, NY 10003', 'Union Square', 'pink'],
  ]);
  var url = 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/48/';

  var options = {
    zoomLevel: 10,
    showTooltip: true,
    showInfoWindow: true,
    useMapTypeControl: true,
    mapType: "normal",
    icons: {
      blue: {
        normal: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Azure-icon.png',
        selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Azure-icon.png'
      },
      green: {
        normal: url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Chartreuse-icon.png',
        selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Right-Chartreuse-icon.png '
      },
      pink: {
        normal: url + 'Map-Marker-Flag-3-Right-Pink-icon.png',
        selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Flag-2-Right-Pink-icon.png'
      }
    }
  };
  var map = new
  google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

  map.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="map_div"></div>
```